# How to write a CSV from Python console in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to write out a CSV file from a vector layer made up of points using the python console in QGIS. I've tried the following command:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer_Map, Folder + "my_shapes.csv", "CP1250", None, "delimitedtext")
```

but it does not like the `delimitedtext` parameter (if I use `ESRI Shapefile` it works fine). I have not been able to determine what other options can be used instead of `ESRI Shapefile`.

I find the Quantum GIS API documentation to be quite confusing, but I hope I will get used to it soon.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please edit your question to include the error.

Comment: No error message, but the number 1 is returned, meaning that the action was not successful. If I use the ESRI Shapefile option the action returns 0 (i.e. successful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the "CSV" argument :

```
currentLayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(currentLayer, csvpath, "CP1250", None, "CSV")
```

I get the 0 exit code, and the CSV file is well created :)